# Return variable back from server to client function with delay in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I call server function from client, that executes UNIX command and get output on server, but I need to return the result back to client function that called it. I get output on server, but Meteor.call immediately returns the result *undefined*, bc exec command takes some time to run. Any advice how to delay getting result and bypass this problem?

**Client Call:**

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.front.events({
    'click #buttondl': function () {
      if (inputdl.value != '') {
        var link = inputdl.value;
        Meteor.call('information', link, function(error, result) {
          if (error)
            console.log(error);
          else 
            console.log(result);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Server method:**

```js
Meteor.methods({
    information: function (link) {

        exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;

        runCommand = function (error, stdout, stderr) {
          console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
          console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

          if(error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
          }
          return stdout;
        }

        exec("youtube-dl --get-url " + link, runCommand);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is being asked about once a week. You can't call return in a callback function. The method will return when it reaches the end of the function, no matter whether the callback of your `exec` has been called or not. That's the nature of asynchronous programming.

You will either need to use a synchronous variant of `exec`, or return the result to the client in some other way (e.g., a collection that is updated reactively).

You can for instance use `execSync` (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options):

```
    return execSync("youtube-dl --get-url " + link);
```